# How to test (recurring) SEPA payments

Tags: civisepa

We are trying to implement (recurring) SEPA payments. The OOFF payments seem to be OK (need to bring them to the bank still to be sure) but when someone makes a recurring contribution all we find in the SEPA dashboard is a OOFF payment. In the database tables we find the following payments. So I have three questions actually:

1. is there anyway we can test these xml's?
2. Is the behavior with recurring payments expected and will the next payments just appear at the right time after running cron job for recurring payments?
3. in contribution details we see as payment method SEPA DD One-off transaction but payment details mentions Credit card as payment method... Is this expected?
   Thank you for your help. I know it is better practice to split up these questions but I have the feeling they could be answered pretty quickly by someone who has a bit more experience with this extension ;-)